# Как сделать так, чтобы в match вошли пробелы между первым и последним числом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Текст:

```
+ 25/50/75/100/125/150/175 ед.
+ 25 /50/75/100/125 /150/ 175 ед.
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пробелы между 25 и 175 так же включались в match, но при этом не включались пробелы слева и справа от чисел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используемое мной регулярное выражение:

```
([0-9]+)\/(([0-9\/]+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/PMqoTp/1

Были попытки сделать это через ( )?, но у меня тогда match обрывается
https://regex101.com/r/gyTOwT/1

Comment: За пробелы отвечает `\s`, а регулярка... не совсем уверен в вашем пожелании, но так `(\s?\d+\s?\/?)` подойдёт?

Comment: \s эквивалентна ( ) 
https://regex101.com/r/jzDWua/1
---------------------------
https://regex101.com/r/gyTOwT/1

Comment: Вы сейчас о чём? Эквивалентна чему? Мою регулярку попробовали?

Comment: Так, судя по всему, запуталась. Можно ссылку на https://regex101.com на вашу регулярку?

Comment: Вчитайтесь в первый мой коммент и увидите подцвеченное — `(\s?\d+\s?\/?)`

Comment: нет, если в таком варианте, то он возьмет пробелы не только между числами, но и слева и справа от них

Comment: добавила картинку

Comment: Картинка мне не нужна, просто ваша формулировка о пробелах так звучала, что я и переспросил правильно ли я понял. Ведь не просто так я вначале воткнул пробельный символ. Попробуйте это — `(\d+\s?\/?)` ...хотя кажется я там ухватил пробел в конце. К сожалению надо убегать. Дела.

Comment: да, понимаю, отредактировала пост

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдёт такая регулярка:

```regex
([0-9]+)\s*\/\s*((?:[0-9\/]\s*(?!е))+)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант покороче. Начинаем захват с цифры `\d`, далее забираем все подряд `.+` и останавливаемся перед пробелом с последующей любой буквой `(?=\s+\p{L})`.

```
\d.+(?=\s+\p{L})
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/DoeK4k/1)

Альтернативный вариант - не выбирать "внутри", а срезать "снаружи" всё, что не цифры (замена по шаблону на '<пусто>'):

```
^[^\d]+|[^\d]+$
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/T5J9Dk/1)